# How to format a JS script?

Tags: javascript, formatting

I have a simple question I am an ethical hacker and I want to see and discover a fake website.
I want to see a JS script from an HTML usually this script is externally put from some website. like Cloudflare.

If you click on this link you can see a JS script. But is it not formatted is here some way how to put this script into a formatted("normal")

[image: link]

a JS script from link:
[image: how I can see it]

Comment: Run it through any JS formatter? But that's only half the battle, and the second half is 99% of the work--figuring out what it actually **does**.

Comment: you are looking for the word minified/unminified. it has nothing to do with formatting.

Comment: just remove the `min` in the file name to view the original sourcecode (wont always work, but in this case it does)

Comment: I use a chrome extension named "JavaScript and CSS Code Beautifier." It does pretty much exactly what you're describing. Normally, I would just copy/paste the code into VSCode and then use Prettier to format everything, but the Chrome extension saves time and is pretty good.

Comment: Click on the `{}` at the bottom of the Source tab. It will reformat the code.